# GNU Make, a command similar to Python's os.path.normpath?

Tags: makefile

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath is perfect.

I have a problem with redundant paths, multiple entries for the same file and it's rather unsightly, it's doing no harm but I'd like to get rid of it.  As you will see a file can be specified several times.

The makefile generates itself (any line with `DEP` in it is building a makefile to be included) and there are some automated tools at play, dependencies of code files (`.cpp`) are generated by GCC with the `-MM` flag, that's how I think these are getting into it. The code file's includes are given relative to that files location. Anyway I'd love to fix this!

```
alec@ATMain ~/cxxtest $ make 
    CREATING    build
    CREATING    build/Structures
    CREATING    build/Thing
    CREATING    build/Thing/listeners
    CREATING    build/implementations
    LISTENER GEN    src/Thing/thing.listener
    LISTENER    src/Thing/thing.listener
    DEP GEN     src/main.cpp
    DEP GEN     src/implementations/thing.cpp
    COMPILE     build/main.o (Due to changes: src/main.cpp src/Thing/thing.h src/Thing/listeners/ThingChangeEmitter.h src/Thing/listeners/../../Structures/LinkedList.h src/Thing/listeners/../../Structures/List.h src/Thing/listeners/../../Structures/Ptr.h src/Thing/listeners/ThingChangeListener.h src/Thing/listeners/../thing.h src/Structures/LinkedList.h src/Structures/Del.h)
    COMPILE     build/implementations/thing.o (Due to changes: src/implementations/thing.cpp src/implementations/../Thing/listeners/ThingChangeListener.h src/implementations/../Thing/listeners/../thing.h src/implementations/../Thing/listeners/ThingChangeEmitter.h src/implementations/../Thing/listeners/../../Structures/LinkedList.h src/implementations/../Thing/listeners/../../Structures/List.h src/implementations/../Thing/listeners/../../Structures/Ptr.h src/implementations/../Thing/thing.h)
    LINK        A.out
alec@ATMain ~/cxxtest $ touch ./src/Thing/thing.h
alec@ATMain ~/cxxtest $ make 
    COMPILE     build/main.o (Due to changes: src/Thing/thing.h src/Thing/listeners/../thing.h)
    COMPILE     build/implementations/thing.o (Due to changes: src/implementations/../Thing/listeners/../thing.h src/implementations/../Thing/thing.h)
    LINK        A.out
alec@ATMain ~/cxxtest $
```

Looking at:
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html

neither real nor abs path seem to do what I want

As I said this doesn't really harm anything, it's just something I'd rather see gone so in:

```
build/%.d: src/%.cpp | builddir $(LISTENERDS:.ld=.lo)
    @echo " DEP GEN     "$< 
    @echo -n $(dir $@) > $@
    @if ! $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -MM $< >> $@; \
    then rm $@; \
    exit 1; \
    fi
    @echo " @echo \"    \"COMPILE\"     \""$$"@""   \"(\"Due to changes: "$$"?\")\"">> $@
    @echo " "$$"("PREFIX")"$$"("CXX")" $$"(CXX_FLAGS)" $$"(INCLUDES) -c $< -o "$$"@" >> $@
```

I expect a solution to apply to the "due to changes" line, not the -MM one. I could write a 2 line Python script to do this but I'd rather not use stuff outside of GnuMake unless I have to (I could of course put this script inside the makefile and have it create then use it :p) but this strikes me as something make ought to be able to do, having said that I can see why it wouldn't need it (different ways of naming the same file).

Comment: This can easily cause a lot of harm. Make is comparing target names by path, so if you have a generated header, but than the compiler refers to it using different path, make will not realize it should remake it.

Comment: @JanHudec I don't see what you mean, do you mean fixing it causes harm or not fixing it? Make determines the age of targets and passes the path to system functions, the system will "simplify" the paths, this is only a visual problem, fixing it does not alter how the makefile works.

Comment: Not fixing it, of course. System functions will resolve the paths, but make does not only pass the paths to system functions, it also compares them. And it does _not_ simplify them when it compares them.

Comment: Ah sorry @JanHudec we have different terminology, if I say a makefile works that implies that it rebuilds what is needed, not that to work it must rebuild ONLY what is needed, having said that I still can't see the problem you mention. Perhaps an example?

Comment: I am only speaking about cases where it does _not_ rebuild what _is_ necessary. Say you had a rule to generate `config.h` (say from `config.h.in`, rather common thing to have), but the compiler saw it as `include/../config.h`. In such case change to `config.h.in` would _not_ trigger rebuild of the sources, because make would not know that `include/../config.h` depends on `config.h.in`, because `"include/../config.h" != "config.h"` though they are actually the same file.

Answer (score 1):

There's no GNU make function like that, nor any simple way to do it with make functions.  The simplest way to do it is to get the compiler to not generate those kinds of paths in the first place.

My suspicion, although you don't provide enough information to tell for sure, is that the value of the `$(INCLUDES)` variable contains values like `-Isrc/Thing/listeners/..` (at least after expansion).  You should modify the setting of these variables so that instead of appending `/..` to the end of the directory, you use the GNU make function (`$(notdir ...)`) to strip off the last directory.  Then these paths would just be `-Isrc/Thing` for example, and you would not have the `..` there.

Comment: Well spotted, I forgot I had Includes, the only things entering this way are wxWidgets flags and that's via CXX_FLAGS, the problem is coming from things reported by GCC with `-MM`, it is spitting out requirements that are simply GCC's WD prepended to the includes.